# Invalid projection when opening geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas, pyproj

I need to do some spatial operations in geopandas. I created the new conda environment and installed geopandas `conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas`. When I run the following simple code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame([Point(1,1)])
gdf.set_geometry(0).set_crs(epsg=3857)
```

I get the following error message :

```
CRSError: Invalid projection: EPSG:3857: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: no database context specified)
```

I tried to google the issue. There are several posts, yet I could not find the right solution. It seems that there is a problem with pyproj database. That's what I understood so far.

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the step `gdf.set_geometry(0)`. Try this instead:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame([Point(1,1)])

# Dont do this
# gdf.set_geometry(0).set_crs(epsg=3857)
# But do it in 2 steps
gdf.set_geometry(0, inplace=True)
gdf.set_crs(epsg=3857, inplace=True)

gdf.plot()
```

Without `inplace=True` in `gdf.set_geometry()`, `gdf` object is not ready to do `.set_crs()`, thus, causes the error.

[image: output]

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your comment. Unfortunately, it does not work. When I run the code you suggested, it still delivers the same error. Also, when I try to open any shape file and change the CRS, it also yields the same error. 

Here with, when I import geopandas (after restarting the kernel) it gives the following warning: `UserWarning: pyproj unable to set database path. _pyproj_global_context_initialize()`

Comment: @AvtoAbashishvili  The error is on your side, which relates to your `pyproj` installation. See the discussion here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363743/initalize-pyproj-correctly .

Comment: Yes, I also found it. They seem to provide the solution here: (https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#internal-proj-error-sqlite-error-on-select)

But the solution is quite shady. I did not really get how to do it.